# how to call res service over secure layer usig .NET?

Tags: .net, rest, https

I am calling REST service over http successfully but over https it fails. I feel it fail because service certificate is not installed properly.  My question is from programming perspective do I have to do any changes in code to call https service? Do I need to load certificate using X509Certificate and assign to service object before making call?  earlier I worked on xml based web service where these kind of things taken care while creating proxy.  Here we are not using add web reference things.  please help.

Comment: Do we really need to install certificate on visual studio to access https ?

Comment: we don't required to load an certificate or any special coding, if server SSL certificate is expired then we need to handle that error.